# Select range of data between two string vlaues

Tags: t-sql

I want select the data in between two string values AAA and DDD. There are data out of range of AAA and  DDD that  I do not want. Any ideas. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: which rows you actually want to select?

Comment: What do you define as "between" `'AAA'` and `'DDD'`?  I don't see any strings in your sample that are `BETWEEN` those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can make of your question, it looks you want the rows between AAA and DDD.

**Table**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id INT, FileN VARCHAR(25), Col1 VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'eee.doc','AAA'),(3,'eee.doc','234'),(4,'eee.doc','tt2'),(7,'eee.doc','wwpp'), 
(8,'eee.doc','DDD'),(9,'eee.doc','tyyyuui'),(10,'ddd.doc','43ffhgd'),(12,'ddd.doc','AAA'),
(14,'ddd.doc','rtty'),(15,'ddd.doc','ppii'),(16,'ddd.doc','hhcc'),(18,'ddd.doc','7ghij'),
(20,'ddd.doc','DDD')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM    @t t
    INNER JOIN (    SELECT  b.*
                    FROM    (   SELECT a.*, LEAD(Id, 1 , NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY FileN ORDER BY a.Id) NextId
                                FROM    (   SELECT  Id, FileN, Col1
                                            FROM    @t t
                                            WHERE   Col1 IN ('AAA','DDD')       
                                        ) a
                            ) b
                    WHERE b.Col1 = 'AAA'
                ) r
        ON t.Id > r.Id  AND t.Id < r.NextId 
ORDER BY 1
```

**Output**

```
Id  FileN     Col1
========================
3   eee.doc   234
4   eee.doc   tt2
7   eee.doc   wwpp
14  ddd.doc   rtty  
15  ddd.doc   ppii
16  ddd.doc   hhcc
18  ddd.doc   7ghij
```

Comment: Thank you. Your syntax works for what I wanted.